# How to work with Grid direction="row" in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to put two select boxes next to each other using the Grid component. No matter if I change the direction of the container they are always stacked on top of each other. I want them side by side.

Here is a screenshot of the page :
[image]

Here is the code:

```
<Grid container>
    <Grid item container direction="row">
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
        <Select
            key={"msSeasons"}
            placeholder={"Seasons.."}
            options={multiSelectArrays.seasons}
            isMulti={true}
            isSearchable={false}
            onChange={e => onSelectChange(e, "seasons")}
        />
        <Select
            key={"msOuts"}
            placeholder={"Outs.."}
            options={multiSelectArrays.outs}
            isMulti={true}
            isSearchable={false}
            onChange={e => onSelectChange(e, "outs")}
        />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a separate grid item for each select element to keep it in a single row :

```js
<Grid container>
    <Grid item container direction="row">
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <Select
                key={"msSeasons"}
                placeholder={"Seasons.."}
                options={multiSelectArrays.seasons}
                isMulti={true}
                isSearchable={false}
                onChange={e => onSelectChange(e, "seasons")}
            />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <Select
                key={"msOuts"}
                placeholder={"Outs.."}
                options={multiSelectArrays.outs}
                isMulti={true}
                isSearchable={false}
                onChange={e => onSelectChange(e, "outs")}
            />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```